# Swift NSURL getResourceValue as NSURLThumbnailDictionaryKey returns nil

Tags: swift, nsurl

I'm trying to get the thumbnail of a several files and it *should* return as an NSDictionary yet keeps returning nil.  For instance, this works:

```
try aURL.getResourceValue(&thumbnails, forKey:NSURLNameKey)
            if let thumbnail = thumbnails as? NSString
            {
                print(thumbnail)
            }
```

But this doesn't (which is what I'm trying to do):

```
try aURL.getResourceValue(&thumbnails, forKey:NSURLThumbnailDictionaryKey)
            if let thumbnail = thumbnails as? NSDictionary//Dictionary<String, NSImage>//Doesn't work either
            {
                print(thumbnail)
            }
```

Anybody have any idea what the problem is here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is printed in `print(thumbnail)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the response -- it's not even being called.  It *is* being called as an NSString though.

Comment: What is printed as `NSString` ?

Comment: The name of the file.  Asking for the NSDictionary keeps returning nil; and yeah the files do have the thumbnail dictionary attribute.